# How to handle feature branch diff creation

Tags: git, diff, phabricator, arcanist

Background -

At my current organization, we use a feature branch development approach. For every new product feature, we create a new feature branch. Its kept up to date with develop (master) branch throughout the development process. Feature work is divided into various tickets branch and then each ticket branch is arc landed to feature branch.

Question -

When I create diff against a develop branch from feature branch, revision gets closed automatically as all the diffs on a feature branch are already approved. Is there a way to make sure that this does not happen? I tried explicitly using --create which does not close the new diff but it squashes all the commits in one when I arc land feature branch PR after approval. Basically, I am looking for a way to create a diff with for a branch which already has n approved diffs and all of them won’t get squashed in one if I land it.

Any comments/feedback highly appriciated.

Comment: I hardly understood what you are trying to achieve, but sounds to me that you didn't get how `git merge` works.

Comment: @0andriy this is not about git merge. This is about phabricator / arcanist workflow.

Comment: If you express your problem in terms of `git`, maybe someone who found your question by the tag could help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to impose a popular github/bitbucket workflow on Phabricator, and have duplicated processes for approval of changes.

That said,
`arc land --merge` should deal with your desire not to squash commits when landing.
Disabling `Autoclose` for the repository (under `Actions`), or customizing the `Autoclose Only` branches (under `Branches`) should avoid the revision being closed when you don't want it to be.